# Creating custom image from Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, disk-image, raspbian

I have five Raspberry Pi 3 devices.

I'm trying to create an image based on the Raspbian image with some additional software installed, then write this new image to the other 4 Pi devices. I'm doing this so I don't have to do all the installations on every Pi.

I did the following steps:

- Wrote the base Raspbian image to an SD card with the tool "win32diskimager" and plugged it into the first Pi.
- Installed the additional software.
- Created a new image with the tool "win32diskimager" from the SD card.
- Wrote the new image to a second SD card and plugged it into a second Pi.

I was able to start the second Pi, but when I opened `raspi-config` there were many errors, such as hardware devices no longer having names:

[image: Empty hardware list]

How can I create this custom image correctly?

Comment: How are you creating the images? What were the errors?

Comment: I created it with "win32diskimager". The error is when i start the raspi-config the hardware devices have no name. I have e.g. 5 devices in my list but no names are shown. I only see 5 empty checkboxes.

Comment: That information should be [edit]ed into your question, including screenshots if they help to clarify it.

Comment: Description and screenshot added

Comment: Use [pi-gen](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen)?